# Ruby equivalent of background scheduler?

Tags: python, ruby

I have this code in Python that I'm trying to rewrite in ruby:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

# Set up the loop
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

job = scheduler.add_job(lambda: person.do_thing, 'interval', seconds=FREQUENCY)
```

How does one do this in Ruby? Note that person has some state on it like name, age, dob, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Rails, you should consider ActiveJob. It supports a variety of backends. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters.html

Otherwise, here is a Ruby equivalent to your code.

```
require 'concurrent'

executor = Concurrent::ThreadPoolExecutor.new

person = { name: 'Bob' }
executor.post(person) { |p| puts "Processing #{p.inspect}" }

executor.shutdown
executor.wait_for_termination
```

See https://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/master/Concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html for more details.